# How to setup mod_security rules only valid for one domain/sub-domain?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, firewall, mod-security, mod-security2

I am building mod_security firewall with proxy to no. of websites. i want to  apply specific rules to only one domain, those rules will not be applicable to other domains.

Example :

> ```
>  SecGeoLookupDb /home/ec2-user/cndata/GeoIP.dat
>  SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:20,drop,msg:'Block India IP address'"
>  SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq IN"
> ```

Above rule i want to aplly to only one sub-domain/domain not other domains. How i can achieve it ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways:

1. Add above rule to vhost for that subdomain only.
2. Change the rule to check the hostname.

For option 2 the new rule could look like this:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:20,drop,msg:'Block India IP address'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "@streq IN" "chain"
SecRule SERVER_NAME "subdomain.example.com"
```

Note the SERVER_NAME will be set by the incoming request so there's nothing stopping an attacker faking this (or not sending this at all), though guessing if this is not set correctly then it won't be routed past the proxy properly anyway.

You can also use regular expressions here, for example to add multiple server names to the last part of the rule:

```
SecRule SERVER_NAME "/subdomain[1-9].example.com/"
```

Or

```
SecRule SERVER_NAME "/^(subdomain|subdomain2).example.com$/"
```

Note: not checked these regexprs wrong on first attempt but hopefully gives you the idea anyway.

Comment: thnx for helping , please let me know if i want to make same rule to set on two hostnames. I tried chaining but not worked. @BazzaDP

Comment: Added that to end of my answer. Alternative to that is to just copy whole rule again if you want to avoid regexprs which can get confusing after a while.

Comment: Thnx , learning a lot , i am using vhost method as i will add more hosts to FW.

Comment: what if I have multiple subdomains and I have to allow all the domains without mentioning them? Is there any wildcard approach to that? Also for the particular URIs under that domain?

Comment: Use a regex: `SecRule SERVER_NAME "/.*\.example\.com/"`